# Focus+Context via Brushing cannot display negative value

Tags: d3.js

Focus+Context via Brushing(bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367), cannot display negative value in big graph.
[graph picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O545.png)

Someone, can tell how can I have negative value in main graph?

But when I use :

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
```

The offset go to min value but the negative part is not inverted in the big graph and I loose inversion in the small graph.
[graph without inverted part in small graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY81H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
```

This sets the `domain` of your data (the range of user space values) from `0` to `max of dataset`.  Change it to this:

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; })));
```

which sets it from `min of dataset` to `max of dataset`.

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

You also need to change the `area.y0` value.  Since `0` is no longer located at height:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
y.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))); //<-- change domain
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

area.y0(y(0)); //<-- set y0 to new location of 0
area2.y0(y2(0));
```

---

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKotc7wACprsI2grntbp?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have modified question for explain what do your solution

Comment: I have search how to but never found.
You are a god.
Thank you very much.